# Laravel 5.5 Export EXCEL

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5

i try to export same data in excel format usinf **Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel** package,it work fine, but i game a problem to make same style for the first row of the excel document:

This is my code :

```
     Excel::create('Adressbook contacts', function($excel) use ($sheetArray,$groupe){
         $excel->sheet($groupe->title, function($sheet) use ($sheetArray)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($sheetArray);
                $sheet->row(1, function($row) {
                    $row->setBackground('#ff6600');
                    $row->setFontColor('#ffffff');
                    $row->setValignment('center');
                });
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
```

The problem is the code make the style by it add a new row in the start on the document :

[image]

Comment: You had the first line if you do not styling ??

Comment: No, it will be deleted

Comment: I am trying to understand your question but i can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys i fix the problem, and i want share it with you:

I chnage the  **$sheet->fromArray()** to this  **$sheet->fromArray($sheetArray, null, 'A1', false, false);**  it make an auto generate heading columns. Thank you for help :D

```
         $excel->sheet($groupe->title, function($sheet) use ($sheetArray)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($sheetArray, null, 'A1', false, false);
                $sheet->row(1, function($row) {
                    $row->setBackground('#ff6600');
                    $row->setFontColor('#ffffff');
                    $row->setFontSize(14);
                    $row->setFontWeight('bold');
                    $row->setAlignment('center');
                });
                $sheet->setStyle(array(
                    'font' => array(
                        'name'      =>  'Roboto',
                        'size'      =>  12
                    )
                ));
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
```